# Can anyone identify this slab serif font that's perfect for branding some blue-collar organisations?

Tags: font-identification, slab-serif

I've run it through what the font and only found similar results.

The unique characteristics I've identified are:

- equal and symmetrical serifs on all 'external' serifs. (Hard to describe, but I'm having a go.)

This characteristic is what told me none of the results I found are correct.

Please could someone help me to identify this font?

[image]

<sub>The picture is from the back doors of a parked vehicle.</sub>

Comment: You can use MyFonts [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) tool for help with identifying fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be this [Square SlabSerif](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/square-slabserif-711/)

- [image]

or multiple others as

[City Pro BE Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/berthold/city-pro/)

[image]

OPTICirrus-Bold

[Berthold City Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/berthold/city-be/)

[image]

Centrum-Bold
...

Comment: I think Square slab is close but on the picture it looks like an extended version and a bit bolder.

Comment: The narrow counter of **O** would indicate it's the cheap version. It does appear to have been stretched, and the **RV** pair is poorly kerned.